# Search result web part - item display template - How to retrieve images from article

Tags: search-results, display-template

I'm trying to show results with a simple display template. But I get a error:

> Cannot read property 'getPictureMarkup' of undefined

How do I retrieve images with search result? I was hoping that I could use the same display template as with CSWP, but clearly not :(

```
var pictureMarkup = Srch.ContentBySearch.getPictureMarkup(pictureURL, 100, 100, ctx.CurrentItem, "cbs-picture3LinesImg", line1, pictureId);
```

Are the Property mappings the same with search result as with CSWP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getPictureMarkup function is only available when using the CSWP. If you want to create a display template to work in both the search result and CSWP, you could better use the following feature: `Src.U.getImageSourceWithRendition(picture, width, height)`.

This function will give you the URL value of the picture managed property with the width and height rendition values: /sites/site1/publishingimages/_88D.jpg?width=100&height=100